# Smooth drag scrolling of an Isometric map - Html5

Tags: html5, isometric, coffeescript

I have implemented a basic Isometric tile engine that can be explored by dragging the map with the mouse. Please see the fiddle below and drag away:

http://jsfiddle.net/kHydg/14/

The code broken down is (CoffeeScript):

**The draw function**

```
draw = ->
  requestAnimFrame draw
  canvas.width = canvas.width

  for row in [0..width]
    for col in [0..height]
      xpos = (row - col) * tileHeight + width
      xpos += (canvas.width / 2) - (tileWidth / 2) + scrollPosition.x
      ypos = (row + col) * (tileHeight / 2) + height + scrollPosition.y
      context.drawImage(defaultTile, Math.round(xpos), Math.round(ypos), tileWidth, tileHeight)
```

**Mouse drag-scrolling control**

```
scrollPosition =
  x: 0
  y: 0

dragHelper = 
  active: false
  x: 0
  y: 0


window.addEventListener 'mousedown', (e) =>
  handleMouseDown(e)
, false

window.addEventListener 'mousemove', (e) =>
  handleDrag(e)
, false

window.addEventListener 'mouseup', (e) =>
  handleMouseUp(e)
, false

handleDrag = (e) =>
  e.preventDefault()
  if dragHelper.active
    x = e.clientX
    y = e.clientY
    scrollPosition.x -= Math.round((dragHelper.x - x) / 28)
    scrollPosition.y -= Math.round((dragHelper.y - y) / 28)

handleMouseUp = (e) =>
  e.preventDefault()
  dragHelper.active = false

handleMouseDown = (e) =>
  e.preventDefault()
  x = e.clientX
  y = e.clientY
  dragHelper.active = true
  dragHelper.x = x
  dragHelper.y = y
```

**The Problem**

As you can see from the fiddle the dragging action is ok but not perfect. How would I change the code to make the dragging action more smooth? What I would like is the point of the map you click on to stay under the mouse point whilst you drag; the same as they have done here:  http://craftyjs.com/demos/isometric/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To move smoother, change

```
scrollPosition.x -= Math.round((dragHelper.x - x) / 28)
scrollPosition.y -= Math.round((dragHelper.y - y) / 28)
```

to

```
scrollPosition.x = Math.round((x - dragHelper.x))
scrollPosition.y = Math.round((y - dragHelper.y))
```

To prevent jumping when first clicking on it, change

```
 dragHelper.x = x
 dragHelper.y = y
```

to

```
 dragHelper.x = x - scrollPosition.x  
 dragHelper.y = y - scrollPosition.y
```

​

And you should be fine.

Not sure why the / 28, did you want it snap to grid?

Comment: Very good, works perfectly. Thank you very much :) The / 28 was to reduce the speed of the grid movement. If only I had > 15 rep then I could up arrow you. Somebody up arrow user18474's answer :p